# Record OPUS audio using QAudioRecorder

Tags: c++, qt, audio-recording, opus, qaudiorecorder

I am recording Opus encoded audio. I wanted to know if Qaudiorecorder is able to record the opus codec?? opus is not included in the supported audio codecs, only pcm is.

If not, what is the best tool to use to record opus encoded audio.

Comment: Recording can *only* be done in PCM; It's the after-the-recording compression that makes usage of compression codecs. Therefore your best bet is to compress the samples using OPUS manually.